# Multiply the i-esim column of a matrix for the i-esim element of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a square matrix $A$ of order $n$ and a vector $\upsilon$ of dimension $n$ as well. Is there a way to combine elements in $\upsilon$ in the form of matrix (let's call this matrix $B$) such that a matrix operation between $B$ and $A$ allows me to get $C$.

Where $C$ is defined as follow:

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
\upsilon_1a_{11} &  \upsilon_2a_{12} & \cdots  & \upsilon_na_{1n} \\ 
\upsilon_1a_{21} &  \upsilon_2a_{22} & \cdots & \upsilon_na_{2n}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
\upsilon_1 a_{n1} &  \upsilon_2a_{n2} & \cdots  & \upsilon_ na_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, $C=AB$ if $B=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&0&\cdots & 0 \\
0& v_2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&0&\cdots & v_n
\end{bmatrix}$.